# Make mandatory to call super class method and to give error when no permission is added in manifest file

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I am trying to make an android library SDK. For this **i need a mandatory call to library super class method when user overides my method** just like need to call super.onDestroy() on onDestroy method in Activity class.

Also **I need a particular permission for my library. If this is not added, and user tries to call my method, need to show an error**.
In my case, i require bluetooth permission for one of my method to execute. If user doesn't give this permission, android studio should show an error to require permission.

I have searched this a lot, but can't find an appropriate answer for this. If we can't do this, is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Support Annotations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#permissions) to cover both use cases: check out [@CallSuper](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#call-super) and [@RequiresPermission](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#permissions).